# Gateway app can not connect to microservices

Tags: docker, microservices, docker-swarm, netflix-eureka, jhipster-registry

we are using Jhipster and docker for our microservices architechture. we just deployed our application stack to docker swarm(docker-compose version 3) with one only one node as active and having issues with Gateway app throwing zuul timeout connecting to backend microservices. We have a different environment where we are not using swarm(docker-compose version 2) and it works great. In swarm I was able curl to backend microservices from Gateway app using containername:port but not containerIp:port. I am lost here as I could not narrow down the issue to whether it is a swarm issue or jhipster issue. I even changed the 'prefer-ip-address: false' in our app properties but it is same issue? Any leads on what the issue could be?

Comment: Could you provide more info about your working environment?

Comment: I am trying this. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2084. I will update if it worked or not

Comment: adding this property to client fixed  issue eureka.instance.hostname=${THE_HOST}